# Context Menu only displaying Types( abstract, class, enum, final, interface ). How is this reverted?

Tags: java, eclipse

I seem to have accidentally hit some shortcut that limited the ability of the context menu. Instead of showing all the methods, variables, etc.; it is only showing the types:

```
abstract
class
enum
final
interface
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which 'context menu' are you asking about?

Comment: What else was there before?